# join multiple jpeg images with low or constant memory footprint

Tags: java, jpeg, javax.imageio

I have multiple images and each image has a resolution of around 2560x10000, I want to join all these images to make one single image. I cannot use the BufferedImage method as the final image and the image I have to join will be in the memory at the same time causing OutOfMemory. So I tried a the below approach:

```
public static void joinJpegFiles(File infile, File outfile, float compQuality,int i) {
    try {
        RenderedImage renderedImage = ImageIO.read(infile);
        ImageWriter Iwriter = null;

        Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg");
        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            Iwriter = (ImageWriter)iter.next();
        }

        ImageOutputStream IOStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outfile);
        Iwriter.setOutput(IOStream);
        IOStream.seek( IOStream.length());
        JPEGImageWriteParam JIWP=new JPEGImageWriteParam(Locale.getDefault());
        JIWP.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT) ;
        JIWP.setCompressionQuality(compQuality);
        Iwriter.write(null, new IIOImage(renderedImage,null,null), JIWP);               
        IOStream.flush();
        IOStream.close();
        Iwriter.dispose();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("write error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This method is called for each image I want to join.
The issue with this approach is that the size of the final image is increasing and equals the sum of sizes of all images I joined, but only the first image is visible when I open the final image. 
I still cant figure out what I am doing wrong and I also couldnt find any sample code to join jpegs other than the BufferedImage and ImageIO.write approach. I read at a news group that it works for tiff format but I need this to work for jpeg/png formats.

Comment: FYI I also used the **Iwriter.write(-1, new IIOImage(renderedImage,null,null), JIWP);** but this throws the Unsupported variant Exception.

Comment: a little bit too late but i have this done with [JMagick](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jmagick/index.php?title=Main_Page), anyone with this problem should at least give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have already solved this, or worked around it somehow, but.. In case anyone else need to solve a similar problem:

It's a little unclear what you are trying to achieve here. Do you really want to create one large image, or create a single file containing multiple images?

**Multiple images in single file:**

Your code seems to append multiple standalone JPEG files into one file. The JPEG (JFIF) format does not support this, and most software will probably just see your file as the first JPEG with loads of junk bytes appended to it at the end. PNG does not allow storing multiple images in one file AFAIK. A format like TIFF does allow multiple images (it even allows you to store them as JPEG streams), which is probably why TIFF was brought up.

However, the JPEG standard has a concept called [Abbreviated Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/jpeg_metadata.html#abbrev), that is very much like how JPEG is usually stored in pyramidal TIFF. The ImageIO `JPEGImageWriter` does support this feature:

> "Abbreviated streams are written using the sequence methods of ImageWriter. Stream metadata is used to write a tables-only image at the beginning of the stream, and the tables are set up for use, using ImageWriter.prepareWriteSequence. If no stream metadata is supplied to ImageWriter.prepareWriteSequence, then no tables-only image is written. If stream metadata containing no tables is supplied to ImageWriter.prepareWriteSequence, then a tables-only image containing default visually lossless tables is written."

I'm not sure how other software will interpret these kinds of files, and according to [the libjpeg docs](http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/jpeg/libjpeg.txt) it probably won't even work:

> "While abbreviated datastreams
>   can be useful in a closed environment, their use is strongly discouraged in
>   any situation where data exchange with other applications might be needed.
>   Caveat designer."

So.. It may or may not be appropriate for your use case.

**Compose multiple images into one large image:**

If on the other hand, you really want to compose multiple images into one large image (and later store as a single JPEG), you could have a look at [some code](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox-common/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/MappedImageFactory.java) I wrote long ago, to allow working with large images, without using heap memory.

It uses [memory-mapped byte buffers](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox-common/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/MappedFileBuffer.java), and might be painfully slow if you don't have enough memory to store the data in RAM. Also, the resulting `BufferedImage` will always be of `TYPE_CUSTOM`, so it will miss most potentially hardware or native acceleration you'll normally benefit from, and some operations may not work on it. However, at least you are not limited by either heap size, nor physical RAM.